# Can I ruin a MIDI device by sending bad data?

Tags: midi

I've got a guitar amp with a midi interface. I'm planning to see what's possible with the device that hasn't been built-in by the manufacturer. Since I have no experience with MIDI I'd like to know if it's possible to ruin a MIDI device by sending wrong data.

I'm not sure what data I'd like to send, and the device is basically a black box without documentation, so I can't give much more details. But one thing I'd like to attempt is overwriting the built-in effects.

Comment: You can learn quite a bit by studying patch dumps.  If you have your device transmit its patches over SysEx, then change one parameter and do it again, you can start to reverse engineer how the patches are stored.  Get cozy with your hex editor though, as this tends to take a few weekends.

Comment: That was my plan :) I just don't want to break my amp, it's quite expensive.

Comment: I'm not sure who manufactures your amp, but I've had good luck getting parts from Roland and Behringer.  If you brick your amp, they might be able to send out a new ROM.

Comment: I sure hope so! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDI commands are parsed and executed by the device's firmware.
Whatever effect(s) a command has is determined by what the firmware is programmed to do when it receives that command.

Typically, unknown commands are ignored, so it should not be possible to ruin a device by sending random data.

Most devices do no have any permanent state.
However, some devices allow upgrading their firmware through MIDI, so if you use the correct SysEx command, and manage to get any checksums correct, it would be possible to replace the original firmware with your own code (or some non-code that prevents it from working).